# How do I set folder and language specific indent settings in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation

I'm working on a specific project ([blender](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Style_Guide/C_Cpp)), and I have run into a particular dilemma with their indentation guidelines.

I personally prefer tabs with size 4 for indenting my C/C++ code, but this project specifies 2 spaces for indentation. I also use Python with this project, which according to standard uses 4 space for indentation.

How do I configure VSCode so that, Python has 4-space indents, C/C++ has tab indents with size 4, and C/C++ only inside the specific repo folder uses 2-space indents?

Comment: read the settings page, specify settings based on languageID, you can do this global or only for that workspace

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For global settings, you can use the Settings UI to set `"editor.tabSize"` to 4.

1. Go to the settings UI (`Ctrl+,` or `Ctrl+Shift+P` the type settings or `File > Preferences > Settings`)
2. Search for `Tab Size` and set it to 4. This will be the default for all languages.

Now for the workspace specific settings,

1. In the command palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P`), type `Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings...` and select `C++`.
2. In the UI, select the `Workspace` Tab
3. Search for `Tab Size` and set it to 2.

For reference, or if you find the UI confusing, VSCode saves your settings in two JSON files:

- a user configuration file (Open it from the command palette `Ctrl+Shift+P` then typing `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`,  on linux it is at `~/.config/VSCode/User/settings.json`). It should contain

  ```json
  {
        ...
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        ...
  }
  ```

  Or if you only want to have a tabsize of 4 for python and C++ :

  ```json
  {
        ...
        "[python]": { "editor.tabSize": 4 },
        "[cpp]": { "editor.tabSize": 4 },
        ...
  }
  ```
- a workspace configuration file at `./vscode/settings.json` (it may not exists you didn't set any previous workspace specific settings, you can create it manually of via the command palette with `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)`). It should contain:

  ```json
  {
        ...
        "[cpp]": { "editor.tabSize": 2 },
        ...
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the UI, Open up Settings, then enter a language tag and also something to search for in the search area at the top. Then edit the setting you want. Under the covers, VSCode will enter the correctly formatted setting in its settings.json file.

In the example picture, I had a file which used xml formatting, but did not end with .xml. I wanted to use a tab size of 2.

[image]